# Visual Basic 6 IDE syntax checker problem

Tags: vb6, ide

The Visual Basic 6.0 IDE checks for syntax errors on-the-fly. Every time it finds a syntax error, it pops up an alert dialog. This feature is driving me crazy, as every time I try to cut and paste in the middle of typing a statement, I have to deal with this pop-up.

Is there any way to disable this on-the-fly syntax checking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Goto Tools-> Options and turn off "Auto-Syntax" check.

While you're there Turn On "Require Variable Declaration"

Comment: bahh, beat my by 11 seconds. I'm going to post a screen shot and pwn you!

Comment: It's the "while you're there..." that makes this answer so great

Answer (score 7):

Yes. In the Tools->Options menu, there is a checkbox called "Auto Syntax Check." Disable this option:

[alt text http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/9809/vbsyntaxcheckdh9.png](http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/9809/vbsyntaxcheckdh9.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub optBlue_Click()
txttext.ForeColour = vbBlue
End Sub

Private Sub optGreen_Click()
txttext.ForeColour = vbGreen
End Sub

Private Sub optRed_Click()
txttext.ForeColour = vbRed
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**